# Debugging with Visual Studio using Local IIS from mapped network drive

Tags: visual-studio, iis

Am trying to configure my project in Visual Studio 2015 to run in Local IIS. The difficulty is that the source files sit on a mapped network drive. The project runs but is unable to load any resources such as css or js files. If I try to navigate directly to the files I get following error:
[image: Unauthorised resources]

I have tried granting the Anonymous Logon user Read permissions but no change. Have tried granting IIS_IURS for my local machine permissions but can not select my machine as a location on the mapped drive.

Any other ideas I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have managed to get round by setting a user in IIS with the following steps

1. Drill down to site
2. Click "Basic Settings" from the Actions menu
3. Click "Connect as..."
4. Select "Specific user" and click set
5. Enter authenticated user credentials and click "OK"

This should allow the resources to be accessed correctly

Hope this is helpful to someone